# jQuery select/deselect all and individual checkboxes within closest table

Tags: jquery

I have dynamic grid-based tables in the application I am developing.

The following code works, but I need a little functionality added to it:

**Current script does the following:**

1. script sees first checkbox.
2. click first checkbox selects/deselects all checkboxes within the closest table.

**New functionality wanted:**

3. script sees first checkbox.
4. click first checkbox selects/deselects all checkboxes within the closest table.
5. **select/deselect individual checkboxes in table**

here is the jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

//this code works for select ALL, but not individual checkbox select/deselect; 
$('td input:checkbox').click(function(e) {
  var table = $(e.target).closest('table');
  $('td input:checkbox', table).attr('checked', e.target.checked);
  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on the question. Can't the user current select/deslect individual checkboxes in the table just by clicking on the checkboxes in the table?

Or, is the first checkbox supposed to change to support a tri-state...select all/de-select all/preserve whatever checkbox preferences were set initially?

Comment: The first checkbox selects/deselects ALL checkboxes in the table.

In the current code (above) you can not deselect or select just one of the checkboxes. 

Clicking any individual checkbox in any row will again select/deselect all checkboxes in that table.

Comment: To rephrase the question: I would like jquery that: 1) has one checkbox to select/deselect ALL checkboxes in a particular table (.closest). 2) you could select/deselect an individual checkbox within the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i figured it out after futsing with it for waaaaay too long:

i added classes to the two different checkboxes and referenced them in the jquery.

```
$('td input:checkbox.selectAll').click(function(e) {
   var table = $(e.target).closest('table');
     $('td input:checkbox.selectIndividual', table).attr('checked', e.target.checked);
});
```